# Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors. Unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

guys.

I have web-site, which is built on codeigniter.

I made it about 1.5 weeks ago.

In database.php I had

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'somehosting.com';`

It worked until today fine. But about two hours ago, there was error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

I wrote mysqli connection script, to found out error and it was:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1129): Host 'somehosting' is blocked because of many connection errors;
```

Then I googled and found solution. I changed

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'somehosting.com';`

with:

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';`

and now everything is working again.

But what means "many connection errors" and why those errors were made​​?

can someone explain me, what happened there?

Comment: repeated login failures? e.g. your account in mysql is `user@x.x.x.x.` as an IP address, and your host suddenly changed IP's. now `somehosting.com` maps to `y.y.y.y` instead and won't get access, because it's a different IP.

Comment: Use a search engine of your choice and find [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blocked-host.html). The reason for failing connections may be aborted scripts, wrong credentials or the likes. When connecting to `localhost`, the client host name changes as well.